# Parse entries from a Reddit post

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, reddit

This is part of a program I'm working on to help me manage an event in a subreddit I'm involved with. The snippet here parses a post and returns the relevant information.

I think I'm most interested in feedback on how I've set up the unit tests. Also, if there's any cleaner way to extract the information.

Handling invalid input is something I have not started yet.

**src/pianojam.py**

```
import configparser
import re

import praw
import praw.models

DELIMITER = '---'  # type: str
CATEGORIES = ['Jazz', 'Classical', 'Ragtime', 'Video Game / Anime / Film']  # type: [str]


def init_reddit(config_pathname: str) -> praw.Reddit:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_pathname)
    return praw.Reddit(client_id=config['RedditParams']['client_id'],
                       client_secret=config['RedditParams']['client_secret'],
                       user_agent=config['RedditParams']['user_agent'])


REDDIT = init_reddit('config.ini')


class Piece(object):
    """A piece to be listed in the piano jam"""

    def __init__(self, piece_text: str):
        # Expected format: Composer: [Title](url) | [Sheet Music](sheetUrl)
        self.composer = piece_text[:piece_text.index(':')]  # type: str
        self.title = re.findall(re.compile('\[(.*?)\]'), piece_text)[0]  # type: str
        urls = re.findall(re.compile('\((.*?)\)'), piece_text)
        self.video_url = urls[0]  # type: str
        self.score_url = urls[1]  # type: str


def format_title(category: str) -> str:
    return '**{}**'.format(category)


def parse_pieces(section_text: str) -> [Piece]:
    pieces = section_text.split('\n')[1:]  # First line is the category; discard
    return (Piece(piece_text) for piece_text in pieces if piece_text.strip() != '')

def get_selections_from_jam(jam_text: str) -> [Piece]:
    sections = jam_text.split(DELIMITER)
    sections = (section.strip() for section in sections)
    filtered_sections = []
    for section in sections:
        section = section.strip()
        for category in CATEGORIES:
            category = format_title(category)
            if section.startswith(category):
                filtered_sections.append(section)
                break
    pieces = []
    for section in filtered_sections:
        pieces.extend(parse_pieces(section))
    return pieces


def get_selections_from_url(url: str) -> [Piece]:
    post = praw.models.Submission(REDDIT, url=url)
    return get_selections_from_jam(post.selftext)
```

**tests/test_parsing.py**

```
import unittest

import pianojam
from pianojam import Piece


class TestParsingJam(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.jam_text = ("\n"
                        "**Submissions from last month's Piano Jam**\n"
                        "\n"
                        "[Submission information]\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "**Guidelines:**\n"
                        "\n"
                        "[Guidelines]\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "[Composition]\n"
                        "\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "**Classical**\n"
                        "\n"
                        "Classical Composer: [Classical Title](url) | [Sheet Music](sheetUrl)\n"
                        "Second Composer: [Another Title](nextPieceUrl) | [Sheet Music](secondSheetUrl)\n"
                        "\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "**Jazz**\n"
                        "\n"
                        "Jazz Composer: [Jazz Title](jazzUrl) | [Lead Sheet](leadUrl)\n"
                        "\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "---\n"
                        "\n"
                        "Have fun!")
    def testGrabsAllSelections(self):
        selections = pianojam.get_selections_from_jam(self.jam_text)
        self.assertEqual(len(selections), 3)

    def testSelectionPopulatedCorrectly(self):
        selections = pianojam.get_selections_from_jam(self.jam_text)
        jazz_piece = None  # type: Piece
        for selection in selections:
            if selection.title == "Jazz Title":
                jazz_piece = selection
                break

        self.assertIsNotNone(jazz_piece, 'No piece with title "Jazz Piece"')
        self.assertEqual(jazz_piece.composer, 'Jazz Composer')
        self.assertEqual(jazz_piece.video_url, 'jazzUrl')
        self.assertEqual(jazz_piece.score_url, 'leadUrl')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move your `jam_text` text into a separate file or a multiline constant string to keep the test itself cleaner.

Also, this block:

```
jazz_piece = None  # type: Piece
for selection in selections:
    if selection.title == "Jazz Title":
        jazz_piece = selection
        break
```

can be simplified via using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
jazz_piece = next((selection for selection in selections if selection.title == "Jazz Title"), None)
```

Note about naming - even though the class name and the `setUpClass` should be in camel case and they are, your test methods should not be - use `lower_case_with_underscores` naming style for them.

Aside from that, since this code is going grow, look into parameterizing your tests with [`subtests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests), or using [`ddt` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ddt), or using [`pytest` fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

Measure code coverage and make sure you cover not only the "happy" paths, but the error-handling paths as well.

And, I think you can even apply some [*Property-based Testing*](http://hypothesis.works/articles/what-is-property-based-testing/) - check out [`hypothesis` library](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python) - I cannot stress enough how much did it help me in unit-testing and catching the bugs I was not even thinking about.